# XML Node query to get all valuenames

Tags: t-sql

I have a table (Table1) which has a coloumn by name XMLColoumn a part of the xml is like

```
<StudentSubjects>
   <ValueName>Maths</ValueName>
   <ValueName>Science</ValueName>
   <ValueName>History</ValueName>
   <ValueName>Calculus</ValueName>
</StudentSubjects>
```

My table is (Table1) something like

```
StudentNo   XMLColoumn(textfile)
 112           (above XML)
 1445          (same structure as above XML)
```

I am trying to get output as

```
StudentNo     Subjects
112           Maths
112           Science
112           History
112           Calculus
```

my findings till now was

```
SELECT
     convert(XML,CAST(XMLCOLOUMN AS nvarchar(max)).value('(//StudentSubjects/ValueName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),StudentNo from Table1
```

Which returns me only the first row ie maths..how can i get all the `<ValueName>?`
Please let me know i tried a lot to find...but couldnt.Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`nodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to shred the XML to rows.

```
select StudentNo,
       N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Subjects
from Table1
  cross apply XMLColumn.nodes('/StudentSubjects/ValueName') as X(N)
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67874)